# is there any way to read DFA from file in C and use is as a compiler?

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-construction

in the read function
i want to store transitions from a file into AfdTransition but it look like m not getting anywhere.

Example of transition in my file :

> 0 number 1

> 0 = 1

0 is start state, 'number' is the condition and 1 is final state

i cant do that because my file contains whitespaces.

This my afd structure:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


typedef struct
{
    char StartState [3];
    char condition[10]; 
    char toState [3];
} AfdTransition;

typedef struct
{
    int startStateID;
    int currentStateID;
    int numberOfStates;
    int NumberofTransitions;
    char Finalstates [100];
    char statesValue [100];
    AfdTransition transition [50];
} Afd;
Afd* read(char * fileName);
void print(Afd * M);
```

and this is my read function :

```
Afd* read(char * fileName)
{
    int i = 0;
    Afd * afd = (Afd*)malloc(sizeof(Afd));
    FILE* filePointer;
    int bufferLength = 255;
    char buffer[bufferLength];
    filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r");
    while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, filePointer))
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            afd->numberOfStates = atoi(buffer);
        }
        else if(i == 1)
        {
            strcpy(afd->statesValue,buffer);
            
        }
        else if(i == 2)
        {
            afd->startStateID = atoi(buffer);
            afd->currentStateID = atoi(buffer);
        }
        else if(i == 4)
        {
            strcpy(afd->Finalstates,buffer);
        }else if(i != 3)
        {
            
            //I want to copy transitions here
        }
        i++;
    }
    afd->NumberofTransitions = i-5;
    fclose(filePointer);
    return afd;
}
```

Comment: Not really sure about what you a call a compiler, to parse a text file you can use [scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: Things will become much simpler, if you get rid of the strings and character arrays. (you could add them later)

Comment: Your read function could definitely be optimized more :)

Comment: @Xilpex thats my problem i dont know how to parse the file data into my afd, what changes can i do so it can be optimized and does the job.